# Как продублировать элемент пользовательского интерфейса в Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Разрабатываю мультидисплейное приложение на Unity3D 2018.3.

Приложение расчитывается запускать на машине с 3 дисплеями. Необходимо, чтобы некоторые элементы пользовательского интерфеса дублировались. Т.е. для каждого из мониторов существует свой Canvas со своими элементами. Но на каждом из них есть кнопочка открывающая панельку с определённым набором элементов, пусть это будут слайдеры. Так вот, изменяя значение слайдера на одном Canvas-е дублирующие слайдеры должны изменяться и на других Canvas-ах.

Самым простым способом я вижу создание скрипта в который помещаю ссылку на дублирующий слайдер и там подписываюсь на event изменения значения. Это легко в реализации, но слишком неудобно в использовании. А если  меня только слайдер дублировать надо, но ещё и `InputField` или ещё чего-нибудь кастомное придумается? Для каждого писать подобный скрипт? Это же не удобно!

Есть ли какое-то другое решение? Прошу, предлагайте идеи!

**UPD:**
Код который себе представляю:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Slider))]
public class DublicateSlider : MonoBehaviour {        
    [SerializeField] private Slider[] _sliders;
    private Slider _thisSlider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _thisSlider = GetComponent<Slider>();
        foreach (var slider in _sliders) {
            slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(value => _thisSlider.value = value);
        }
    }

}
```